# Adding Custom Image Styles to the Ribbon

Tags: ribbon, custom, css, html-editor

I use the following Editor Control, with the PrefixStyleSheet "el-" for my custom styles:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="f55c4d88-1f2e-4ad9-aaa8-819af4ee7ee8" HasInitialFocus="True" MinimumEditHeight="400px" PrefixStyleSheet="el-" runat="server" />
```

And all my custom Markup Styles are working, like this:

```
H1.el-Element-h1 {
  -ms-name: "Heading 1";
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AF0917;
  color: #AF0917;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
...
```

but the image styles don't work:

```
.el-rteImage-0 {
  -ms-name:"No Border";
}
.el-rteImage-1 {
  -ms-name:"Border";  
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 2px;  
}
```

What did i wrong?

Comment: Ok i have it, sorry ^^.
The default Microsoft Share Prefix is "ms-rte", and my is "el-" so instead of
`.el-rteImage-0`

i have to use
`.el-Image-0`

Comment: Write that as an answer to the question, and mark it as the correct answer and you might help others looking for the same thing!